# Question involving infima

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is nonempty and bounded and contains both positive and negative values. For every $\varepsilon  \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$, if there is an $x \in X$ with $x < \inf(X) + \varepsilon$, is it true that $-\inf(X) - \varepsilon < |x|$?

Comment: Yes. If $x<\varepsilon+\inf X$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then necessarily $x=\inf X.$ On the other hand, since $X$ contains negative values then of course $\inf X<0.$ Now, I'm a bit confused about your statement. First, from what you say, one understands that $\epsilon$ is some fixed value. However, later on, you say "...for every $\varepsilon$" (I understand it should be positive and distinct to the original epsilon?).

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: Does this change anything?

Comment: Yes, it is true. To show it, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $x\in X$ be such that $x<\inf X+\varepsilon.$ Then $-\inf X-\varepsilon<-x.$ Now note that if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$ and if $x\geqslant0$ then $|x|=x\geqslant-x.$

Comment: Nevermind. That makes sense. I screwed my attempt up.

Comment: Ok thanks! If $x \geq 0$ then $|x| = x$ so we have $x \geq -x$ which is true. Now if $x < 0$ then $|x| = -x$ so we have $-x \geq -x$ which is also true. Therefore, $-$inf($X) - \varepsilon < -x \leq |x|$.